# UISwitch move to OFF state when back button used

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `main window` where i use a setting `button` used with `navigation controller`. I have a `view controller` where i kept my `UISwitch`. My `UISwitch` works well with its functionality but when i go back the switch turns "**OFF**" automatically.

I tried using these,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

but then the same problem exists. Since i have only one view controller i cant retrieve the `NSUserDefaults`.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is the view being recreated every time you go into it?

Comment: Why can't you use the `boolForKey:` method on the user defaults when you initialize the view controller with the UISwitch? What do you mean by "I can't retrieve the NSUserDefaults"? `standardUserDefaults` is a singleton, you can use it from anywhere.

Comment: @sbarow am not sure about it. how to know that?

Comment: @allprog I tried `boolForKey:` method still its not maintaining its state as "ON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup your view, either in the init method or in viewDidLoad do something like this.

```
[startTrackingButton setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switchValue"]]
```

Then every time you switch is toggled save the state of the switch

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

*"Since i have only one view controller i cant retrieve the NSUserDefaults."*

You can retrive the user defaults in the `viewDIdLoad` to read the switch position in that one view

So if you have only one `viewController`

1. save to `NSSsuserDefaults` as you are doing
2. In viewDidLoad read the switch state to retrive the position of the switch

save switch state in your switch action method

```
 if (sender == _switch) {
    BOOL mySwitchValue = [ sender isOn ];
    NSString *tmpString = mySwitchValue ? @"1" : @"-1" ;
    NSUserDefaults  *myNSUD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [ myNSUD setObject:tmpString forKey: @"mySwitchValueKey" ];
    [ myNSUD synchronize ];


    //save a key to read switch state in another view if required
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setBool:self.barCodeSwitch.on forKey:@"switch1"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

  }


}
```

Read the saved switch position in viewDidLoad

```
NSUserDefaults  *myNSUD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *tmpString =  [ myNSUD stringForKey: @"mySwitchValueKey"];
    BOOL mySwitchValue = NO;  // or DEFAULT_VALUE on/off
    if (tmpString != nil) {
        mySwitchValue = ( [ tmpString intValue ] == 1 );
    }
    [_autocompleteSwitch setOn: mySwitchValue];
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it using, `NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`
`BOOL state = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switchValue"];` but don't know how to maintain its state

Comment: I tried with your source now it maintains the ON state but if i use back button the location tracking stops. Any idea. Updated question with code. please check it.

Comment: You need to ask another question for that.  That is a separate question to your original which we have answered for you